# MongoDB query is performing slow when using $in operator

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

With some complex queries and aggregation, I got the list of object ids as below:

```
var objectIdsCollection = Array of ObjectIds
```

I have another collection, it's say Collection1 and It has OtherCollectionObjectId. Now, I need to filter this Collection1 based on object ids I got in an array.

```
Collection1 {
   _id: ObjectId('xyz'),
   name: ..
   someOtherAttributes: ...
   OtherCollectionObjectId: ObjectId('abc')
}
```

Below is the query which I am trying. I need to use await because, the result of this query is dependent on another query.

```
let queryData = await Document1.aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              OtherCollectionObjectId: {
                $in: objectIdsCollection,
              },
              Deleted: false,
            },
          },
        ]);
```

But, this query is performing way slow. Sometimes it takes around 1 minute to fetch the results.

I tried couple of other suggestions from internet but nothing seems to work for this kind of scenario.

Please let me know anything which can improve the performance of this query.

Thanks

Comment: How many documents are roughly contained in this collection and how large is the `objectIdsCollection` array you pass to the call?

Comment: Hi @FabianStrathaus, Document1 roughly contains around 1,00,000 records and objectIds collection will hold around 1000 or 2000 roughly.

Comment: I assume you didn't specify an index on `OtherCollectionObjectId` property yet, correct? This would be something you can try. Apart from that I don't think there is much you can do, since this is an inherently expensive operation. Maybe you can also think about this query from a use case perspective. Are you really trying to find matches for 1000 to 2000 different values?

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to help. Please edit your question to include the `output of .explain("executionStats")` for the query so that we can begin to narrow down the problem. With that we will be able to confirm things like index usage (as @FabianStrathaus was pointing out) and other efficiency metrics. Broadly speaking it should certainly be possible to return 1k to 2k documents from the database in less than a minute